# after use ajax function page keep reload

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

i have an link in my page as the following :

```
<input onkeydown="check_me(event,this,\''. $post['id'] .'\',\''.$access_token.'\');" id="comment_msg" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Write a comment" />
```

so am calling the following function :

```
function check_me(event,element,post_id,access_token){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        fb_comment(post_id, access_token,element);        
    }

}       
function fb_comment(post_id, token,element){                 
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "comment_post.php",
        data: 'id='+post_id+'&token='+token+'&comment='+element.value,
        success: function(html)
        {           
          element.value='';                            
        }

    });    
}
```

problem is after submitting the the element value the page reload , how can i stop reloading the page after submitting the element value!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser tries to submit the form if you press `return`. So just add `onsubmit=return false` to your form tag - or remove it.

```
<form onSubmit="return false">
    <input onkeydown="...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your first, wrapper function, write :

```
    event.preventDefault();
```

Because the default behaviour is reloading the page. Correct me if I am wrong